# Battleship game crashes if I click outside of grid. How do I stop this?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm relatively new to pygame (and writing code in general), so I decided to make a battleship game for my project. The game is relatively simple, ships will be randomly placed and the player has a set amount of shots to find and sink all ships else they lose. However, I have made a grid which responds to player input but if the player clicks outside of the grid (a small area under the grid which will show information like the total shots remaining) the game shows an error and stops. How do I fix this?

Here is my code so far:

```
import pygame, random, sys
from sys import exit
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

SCREENWIDTH = 255
SCREENHEIGHT = 300
GRIDWIDTH = 20
GRIDHEIGHT = 20
MARGIN = 5
FPS = 60

BLACK    = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE    = (255, 255, 255)
RED      = (255,  0,    0)
GREEN    = (  0, 255,   0)
GRAY     = ( 60,  60,  60)
BLUE     = (  0,   0, 255)
YELLOW   = (255, 255,   0)
TURQUOISE= (  0, 100, 100)

SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("BATTLESHIPS")
FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
MAIN_BACK = pygame.image.load("Water back.jpg")
PLAY_BUTTON_IMAGE = pygame.image.load("Start-Button-Vector-PNG.png")
HEADING_FONT = pygame.font.Font(None, 60)
HEADING = HEADING_FONT.render("Battleships", True, WHITE)
MENU = True
PLAYING = False

GRID = []
for ROW in range(10):
    GRID.append([])
    for COLUMN in range(10):
        GRID[ROW].append(0)

class Button():
    def __init__ (self, x, y, image, scale):
        width = image.get_width()
        height = image.get_height()
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (int(width * scale), int(height * scale)))
        self.rect.topleft = (x, y)
        self.clicked = False 

    def draw(self):
        action = False 
        if PLAY_ON == False:
            return

        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos() 
        
        if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.clicked == False:
                self.clicked = True
                action = True
            #endif
        #endif
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
            self.clicked = False
        #endif
        
        SCREEN.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y)) 

        return action

PLAY_BUTTON = Button(3, 125, PLAY_BUTTON_IMAGE, 0.5)
PLAY_ON = True

def draw_grid():
    for ROW in range(10): 
        for COLUMN in range(10):
            COLOR = WHITE 
            if GRID[ROW][COLUMN] == 1:
                COLOR = GREEN 
            pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN,
                             COLOR, 
                             [(MARGIN + GRIDWIDTH) * COLUMN + MARGIN,
                              (MARGIN + GRIDHEIGHT) * ROW + MARGIN,
                              GRIDWIDTH,
                              GRIDHEIGHT])


    
SCREEN.fill(TURQUOISE)
PLAY_BUTTON.draw()
SCREEN.blit(HEADING, (10,20))

pygame.display.update()

while MENU == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
            
        elif PLAY_BUTTON.draw() == True and PLAY_ON == True:
            PLAY_ON = False
            PLAYING = True
            SCREEN.fill(BLUE)
            draw_grid()
            MENU = False

    FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)

    pygame.display.update()

while PLAYING == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            POS = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            COLUMN = POS[0] // (GRIDWIDTH + MARGIN)
            ROW = POS[1] // (GRIDHEIGHT + MARGIN)
            GRID[ROW][COLUMN] = 1
            draw_grid()

    FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

you must check that `COLUMN` and `ROW` are within the range of the grid::

```py
while PLAYING == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # [...]

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            POS = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            COLUMN = POS[0] // (GRIDWIDTH + MARGIN)
            ROW = POS[1] // (GRIDHEIGHT + MARGIN)

            if 0 <= ROW < 10 and 0 <= COLUMN < 10:
                GRID[ROW][COLUMN] = 1
                draw_grid()
```